# Heading identification with Regex

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, pdf

I'm wondering how I can identify headings with differing numerical marking styles with one or more regular expressions assuming sometimes styles overlap between documents. The goal is to extract all the subheadings and data for a specific heading in each file, but these files aren't standardized. Is regular expressions even the right approach here?

I'm working on a program that parses a .pdf file and looks for a specific section. Once it finds the section it finds all subsections of that section and their content and stores it in a `dictionary<string, string>`. I start by reading the entire pdf into a string, and then use this function to locate the "marking" section.

```
private string GetMarkingSection(string text)
    {
      int startIndex = 0;
      int endIndex = 0;
      bool startIndexFound = false;
      Regex rx = new Regex(HEADINGREGEX);
      foreach (Match match in rx.Matches(text))
      {
        if (startIndexFound)
        {
          endIndex = match.Index;
          break;
        }
        if (match.ToString().ToLower().Contains("marking"))
        {
          startIndex = match.Index;
          startIndexFound = true;
        }
      }
      return text.Substring(startIndex, (endIndex - startIndex));
    }
```

Once the marking section is found, I use this to find subsections.

```
private Dictionary<string, string> GetSubsections(string text)
    {
      Dictionary<string, string> subsections = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      string[] unprocessedSubSecs = Regex.Split(text, SUBSECTIONREGEX);
      string title = "";
      string content = "";
      foreach(string s in unprocessedSubSecs)
      {
        if(s != "") //sometimes it pulls in empty strings
        {
          Match m = Regex.Match(s, SUBSECTIONREGEX);
          if (m.Success)
          {
            title = s;
          }
          else
          {
            content = s;
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
            {
              subsections.Add(title, content);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return subsections;
    }
```

Getting these methods to work the way I want them to isn't an issue, the problem is getting them to work with each of the documents. **I'm working on a commercial application so any API that requires a license isn't going to work for me.**
These documents are anywhere from 1-16 years old, so the formatting varies quite a bit. [Here is a link to some sample headings and subheadings from various documents.](https://regex101.com/r/6RckWL/5) But to make it easy, here are the regex patterns I'm using:

- Heading: `(?m)^(\d+\.\d+\s[ \w,\-]+)\r?$`
- Subheading: `(?m)^(\d\.[\d.]+ ?[ \w]+) ?\r?$`
- Master Key: `(?m)^(\d\.?[\d.]*? ?[ \-,:\w]+) ?\r?$`

Since some headings use the subheading format in other documents I am unable to use the same heading regex for each file, and the same goes for my subheading regex.

My alternative to this was that I was going to write a master key (listed in the regex link) to identify all types of headings and then locate the last instance of a numeric character in each heading (5.1.X) and then look for 5.1.X+1 to find the end of that section.

That's when I ran into another problem. Some of these files have absolutely no proper structure. Most of them go from 5.2->7.1.5 (5.2->5.3/6.0 would be expected)

I'm trying to wrap my head around a solution for something like this, but I've got nothing... I am open to ideas not involving regex as well.

Here is my updated `GetMarkingSection` method:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> GetMarkingSection(string text)
    {
      var headingRegex = HEADING1REGEX;
      var subheadingRegex = HEADING2REGEX;
      Dictionary<string, string> markingSection = new Dictionary<string, string>();

      if (Regex.Matches(text, HEADING1REGEX, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline).Count > 0)
      {
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(text, headingRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline))
        {
          if (Regex.IsMatch(m.ToString(), HEADINGMASTERKEY))
          {
            if (m.Groups[2].Value.ToLower().Contains("marking"))
            {
              var subheadings = Regex.Matches(m.ToString(), subheadingRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline);
              foreach (Match s in subheadings)
              {
                markingSection.Add(s.Groups[1].Value + " " + s.Groups[2].Value, s.Groups[3].Value);
              }
              return markingSection;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      else
      {
        headingRegex = HEADING2REGEX;
        subheadingRegex = HEADING3REGEX;

        foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(text, headingRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline))
        {
          if(Regex.IsMatch(m.ToString(), HEADINGMASTERKEY))
          {
            if (m.Groups[2].Value.ToLower().Contains("marking"))
            {
              var subheadings = Regex.Matches(m.ToString(), subheadingRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline);
              foreach (Match s in subheadings)
              {
                markingSection.Add(s.Groups[1].Value + " " + s.Groups[2].Value, s.Groups[3].Value);
              }
              return markingSection;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
```

Here are some example PDF files:
[image: Style 1]
[image: Style 2]

Comment: I am afraid, your made-up sample does not help a lot. I looks like there is no silver bullet for your issue.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I can't share the documents, but they follow no discernible pattern so it's turning out to be very difficult to identify sections in this way.

Comment: Looking at your regex, they could be simplified to remove the ` ?` with no difference in how they work, because of the already existing adjacent character class containing a space. The inclusion of `\r?` is also a iffy, since `\r` will be equivalent and probably obsoleted by `$`. As to your actual issue, `My alternative to this was that I was going to write a master key... and then look for 5.1.X+1 to find the end of that section... [However], most of them go from 5.2->7.1.5`, ...

Comment: ... The best potential strategy here seems to be to initially use a regex to find sections, and then store the text between these sections as the sections' text. When it comes to creating a dictionary with subsections, all that's required is a function to check the numbering of consecutive sections to see if they are subsections, and handle accordingly. Given this scenario, the section text and subsection hierarchy building (or whatever) obviously can't be accomplished simultaneously.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to tell if it's a section or subsection because the format varies between documents. What might be a section in one could be a subsection in another and vice versa.

Comment: Are the formats of the different documents really totally arbitrary? Or is there at least a limited set (like a dozen or so) of types of documents formatted alike? You say that *these documents are anywhere from 1-16 years old, so the formatting varies quite a bit* which makes it sound like those documents might be of such a limited set of types...

Comment: From what I have seen there are at least 5 different styles, but none of the formats make any sense in terms of structure.

Comment: Please share example pdfs of each style.

Comment: The PDFs contain confidential information. I am unable to share them. Some example headings and sub-headings can be found in the regex101 link I shared. It is important to mention that the number format doesn't always match either. A document might jump from 5.2.3 to 8.4.1 for no apparent reason.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting downvoted. I researched and tried several different methods before posting and I also provided a detailed explanation of my problem. If there is no easy solution for this problem then THAT is the answer I'm looking for...

Comment: @emsimpson92, for the documents where the subheading format is used for the heading, do they have sub headings? if yes, what is the format for those subheadings?

Comment: It varies. I haven't examined every file individually, but I've seen some where headings are "5 General" and subheadings are "5.1 general 1", but other files are "5.1 General" and "5.1.1 general 1"

Comment: @mkl I updated the post with dummy pdf examples

Comment: @Matt.G I updated the post with dummy pdf examples

Comment: In your example images (your question update contains images, not pdfs) one can recognize different fonts/styles for the headings. Have you considered using those information, too?

Comment: I was not aware of this possibility. This is something I can do with a free library for commercial use?

Comment: Well, which library are you going to use? (You are aware that requests for library recommendations are off-topic on stack overflow?)

Comment: The only one I've been able to find for free was pdfsharp but I wasn't aware it had this functionality. It seems to be more for *creating* pdfs rather than modifying them.

Comment: Have you considered pdf clown or a .Net port of pdfbox? I assume your talk about licenses excludes libraries available under AGPL, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it does. However it doesn't look like getting the text properties will help at all. The headings and subheadings share the same size, color, etc in most documents. The only difference is the number.

Comment: That's unfortunate. (Add an aside: that means your dummy example images are not representative...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this approach works:

```
var heading1Regex = @"^(\d+)\s(?<title>.*?)$\n(?<content>.*?)$\n*(?=^\d+\s|\Z)";
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TZCAtX/2)

```
var heading2Regex = @"^(\d+)\.(\d+)\s(?<title>.*?)$\n(?<content>.*?)$\n*(?=^\d+\.\d+\s|\Z)";
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vNCVZS/2)

```
var heading3Regex = @"^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\s(?<title>.*?)$\n(?<content>.*?)$\n*(?=^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s|\Z)";
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4MNc24/2)

For each pdf file:

```
var headingRegex = heading1Regex;
var subHeadingRegex = heading2Regex;

if there are any matches for headingRegex
{
    for each match, find matches for subHeadingRegex
}
else
{
    var headingRegex = heading2Regex;
    var subHeadingRegex = heading3Regex;
    //repeat same steps
}
```

**1. Edge case 1: after 5.2, comes 7.1.3**

As shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/4vkMKh/2),
get main section match using heading2Regex.

convert group1 of the match to integer

```
int.TryParse(match.group1, out var headingIndex);
```

get sub section matches for heading3Regex

for each subsection match, convert group1 to integer.

```
int.TryParse(match.group1, out var subHeadingIndex);
```

check if headingIndex is equal to subHeadingIndex. if not handle accordingly.

Comment: I'm one step closer, and I think this method will work, but I need to bend the regex to match all use cases. Thanks! I'll let you know what I find out.

Comment: The good news is that it's working. The bad news is that it's pulling in a ton of false matches. Guess I'm going to be wrestling regex for a while longer.

Comment: @emsimpson92, if you could provide samples of false matches, I could try as well.

Comment: [Here are a couple examples.](https://regex101.com/r/TZCAtX/3) It shouldn't be that big of an issue narrowing it down. The patterns I designed beforehand were made to strictly identify these sort of things.

Comment: [Here are some examples using my heading/subheading master key](https://regex101.com/r/6RckWL/12)

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the title always start immediately after a space (or a fixed number of spaces). Similarly, is it safe to assume that the title starts with alpha-numeric character?

Comment: Yes, titles always start with the section number, followed by a single space and then the name of the section starting with a capital Alphanumeric character as far as I can tell. The second link I posted contains all the different heading types.

Comment: I updated the original post with my updated method as well.