# Regex match subheading titles only

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataframe with a column with titles (see example below)

```
import numpy as np




Fairytales_in = {'Titles': ['Fairy Tales',
                    'Tales.3.2.Dancing Shoes, ballgowns and frogs',
                    'Tales.2.4.6.Red Riding Hood',
                    'Fairies.1Your own Fairy godmother',
                    'Ogres-1.1.The wondrous world of Shrek',
                    'Witches-1-4Maleficient and the malicious curse',
                    'Tales.2.1.The big bad wolf',
                    'Tales.2.Little Red riding Hood',
                    'Tales.2.4.6.1.Why the huntsman is underrated',
                    'Tales.5.f.Cinderella and the pumpkin carriage',
                    'Ogres-1.Best Ogre in town',
                    'No.3.Great Expectations']}

    Fairytales_in = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Fairytales_in)
```

I'd like to create a new column, which contains the exact same string as the titles column, but only when it is a subheading. (e.g. Tales.3.2. or Ogres-1.1. or Witches-1-4 or Tales.5.f).

```
This would be my expected output: 


    Fairytales_expected_output = {'Titles': ['Fairy Tales',
                    'Tales.3.2.Dancing Shoes, ballgowns and frogs',
                    'Tales.2.4.6.Red Riding Hood',
                    'Fairies.1Your own Fairy godmother',
                    'Ogres-1.1.The wondrous world of Shrek',
                    'Witches-1-4Maleficient and the malicious curse',
                    'Tales.2.1.The big bad wolf',
                    'Tales.2.Little Red riding Hood',
                    'Tales.2.4.6.1.Why the huntsman is underrated',
                    'Tales.5.f.Cinderella and the pumpkin carriage',
                    'Ogres-1.Best Ogre in town',
                    'No.3.Great Expectations'],
                    'Subheading': ['NaN', 
                                   'Tales.3.2.Dancing Shoes, ballgowns and frogs',
                                   'NaN',
                                   'NaN',
                                   'Ogres-1.1.The wondrous world of Shrek',
                                   'Witches-1-4Maleficient and the malicious curse',
                                   'Tales.2.1.The big bad wolf',
                                   'NaN',
                                   'NaN',
                                   'Tales.5.f.Cinderella and the pumpkin carriage',
                                   'NaN',
                                   'NaN']}

    Fairytales_expected_output = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Fairytales_expected_output)
```

I keep struggling to find a way to make my pattern match only the subheadings. No matter what I try, first level or third level headings are still included. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768051/heading-identification-with-regex) asks more or less the same, but it's in C# and I wasn't able to make it work on my use case.

This is what I tried so far:

```
Fairytales_in['Subheading'] = Fairytales_in.Titles.str.extract(r'(^(?:\w+\.|\-\d{1}\.\d{1}\.)\W*(?:\w+\b\W*){1,100})$')
```

But as you can see it does not yield the desired results. I've been trying to use regex101.com, but I'm stuck on this for two days now. Any help on fixing my pattern would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
rx = r'^(\w+(?:[.-](?:\d+|[a-zA-Z]\b)){2}(?![.-]?\d).*)'
Fairytales_in['Subheading'] = Fairytales_in['Titles'].str.extract(rx, expand=False)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/geMK49/3)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `(?:[.-](?:\d+|[a-zA-Z]\b)){2}` - two occurrences of a

  - `[.-]`  - a dot or `-`
  - `(?:\d+|[a-zA-Z]\b)` - 1 or more digits or an ASCII letter followed with a word boundary
- `(?![.-]?\d)` - no optional `.` or `-` followed with a digit allowed immediately to the right of the current location
- `.*`  - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible

Pandas test:

```
>>> Fairytales_in['Titles'].str.extract(rx, expand=False)
0                                                NaN
1       Tales.3.2.Dancing Shoes, ballgowns and frogs
2                                                NaN
3                                                NaN
4              Ogres-1.1.The wondrous world of Shrek
5     Witches-1-4Maleficient and the malicious curse
6                         Tales.2.1.The big bad wolf
7                                                NaN
8                                                NaN
9      Tales.5.f.Cinderella and the pumpkin carriage
10                                               NaN
11                                               NaN
Name: Titles, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and elaborate explanation! It works perfectly on the test case, but when I tried it on my actual data, it seems to match two strings that should not be included. I edited my question to add the two cases to my sample dataframe. Would you happen to know how to solve this?

Comment: @AmyV I fixed the pattern. Note you have a comma  missing in your data in the question, after `Witches-1-4Maleficient and the malicious curse` line.